# Changing name of file download from browser app?

Tags: javascript, mapserver, gml, format

I am developing browser application using MapServer and JavaScript. I've got part where on map click I get FeatureInfo about an object:

```
function getFeatureInfoGML(map){
    var openwindowhandle=window.open('', "openwindow")
    if (openwindowhandle){ openwindowhandle.close()}
    map.on('singleclick', function(evt) {
    var viewResolution = /** @type {number} */ (view.getResolution());
    var url = immovableSource.getGetFeatureInfoUrl(
        evt.coordinate, viewResolution, 'EPSG:4326',
        {'INFO_FORMAT': 'gml'});

    if (url) {
                infoWindow=window.open(url, "openwindow", "width=500,height=600");
            }                   
    });

}
```

where

```
    immovableSource = new ol.source.ImageWMS({
        url: 'http://localhost:8000/cgi-bin/mapserv.exe?map=c:/ms4w/project/info.map',
        params: {'LAYERS': 'immovable'},
        ratio: 1,
        serverType: 'mapserver'
        }),
```

in my map file my output format is:

```
OUTPUTFORMAT
    NAME "OGRGML"
    DRIVER "OGR/GML"
    MIMETYPE "text/xml; subtype=gml/2.1.2; driver=ogr"
    FORMATOPTION "STORAGE=memory"
    FORMATOPTION "FORM=multipart"
    FORMATOPTION "FILENAME=rezult.gml"
END
```

When I click on the map a file is downloaded with name "mapserv.exe", but I want it to be *.gml. When I open mapserv.exe it's a GML file, I just want to change the name of the downloaded file.

Comment: Your title and body ask different questions (the title being extremely difficult). Don't you just want to change the *name* of the downloaded file? This very nearly a plain vanilla JavaScript issue (part of the download request).

Comment: @Vince, I really don't know how to fix it and where the problem is. I accept your remark about the title and the body - my fault

Comment: You have to add a [Content-Disposition header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition) to the HTTP response. I don't see a MapServer option; you might need to override this in the web server.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10049259/change-name-of-download-in-javascript

Answer (score 0):

If you want a downloaded file called `result.gml` from a WFS request for a GML output the following works:

```
OUTPUTFORMAT
    NAME "OGRGML"
    DRIVER "OGR/GML"
    MIMETYPE "text/xml; subtype=gml/2.1.2; driver=ogr"
    FORMATOPTION "STORAGE=filesystem"
    FORMATOPTION "FORM=multipart"
    FORMATOPTION "FILENAME=result.gml"
END
```

and in your service WEB > METADATA

```
WEB
    ...
    METADATA
        "WFS_GETFEATURE_FORMATLIST" "CSVSTREAM,JSON,MIDMIF,SHAPEZIP,OGRGML"
        ...
    END
```

and a request like:

> http://xxx/ows?service=WFS&request=GetFeature&version=2.0.0&typenames=ENERGY_STATUS_2016&srsName=EPSG:4326&bbox=2.3319787109375003,32.20465253906251,3.4415978515625003,33.31427167968751,EPSG:4326&outputformat=OGRGML&